# Intent Service crashes my app?

Tags: java, android, onclick, crash, intentservice

There are different Questions that are answered on stack overflow like this question. But the code used in those question is different than that which i am using. I am just calling an intent_service when a button on main activity is pressed. The link below refers to an image and code shows how intent_service is called on pressing the button;

[:The "Send Intent Service" Button on MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqQtg.png)

```
package com.example.mk141.intentservicenotworking;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void start_intent_service(View view)
    {
        Intent intent_service=new Intent(this,Intent_Service.class);
        startActivity(intent_service);
    }
}
```

The code Present In the Intent_Service class is as follow;

```
package com.example.mk141.intentservicenotworking;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.util.Log;
public class Intent_Service extends IntentService
{
    private static final String 
    TAG="com.example.mk141.intentservicenotworking";
    public Intent_Service(String name)
    {
        super(name);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        Log.i(TAG,"Intent Service Started");//I disabled the Inspection but 
                                            // still crashing
                                            // when Intent Service is called
    }
}
```

In the above class a log will be appeared when intent service is called i.e "Intent Service Started". I also Created a TAG and edited a filter so that only one log message appear as show by the following images;

[Editing Filter 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hpeI.png)

[Editing Filter 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Blq6.png)

There was an error i.e characters in TAG can be at most 23. But after disabling Inspection that error is finished as shown in following image;

[Disabling Inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdDWK.png)

But when i run my program and press Start intent Service it Crashes as show by following images;

[app crashes 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezr9T.png)
[app crashes 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaTVG.png)

Please someone help me if he knows how to resolve this error as i cannot continue without resolving this error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should use start service not startActivity
also make sure that the service is not running

Comment: Thank you Sir, Its now working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**

```
startService(intent_service);
```

**instead of**

```
startActivity(intent_service);
```

**For TAG**

Don't use the TAG in LOG statement more than 23 characters.

Comment: The issue with TAG in LOG is resolved when i disabled inspection.

Comment: SBR bans i just tried to use less words but it doesn't display log message on logcat if we do not use package name as it is in TAG.

Comment: @MoonKhanZeeshan Tag does nothing here... it's just a label to identify your message in logs..